# Is there anything else than DNS leaks that I should be aware of while using VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Is there anything else than DNS-leaks that I should be aware of while using VPN that could potentially leak my real IP address?

Comment: Please add more details to this question. Are you concerned about security ? privacy ? latency ? integrity ? other ?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of additional information in the question. I am concerned about my privacy. I don't really care about the latency. In what way can the integrity be affected?

Comment: Can't be bothered to write full answer but WebRTC leaks are another very real threat.

Comment: Privacy from whom? Unless you took great care when signing up, law enforcement can likely backtrack you through your VPN.

Comment: Privacy from private individuals not governments (its almost impossible for rookies like me).

Comment: Why would you use VPN instead of using Tor? It is designed for privacy.

Comment: VPN's provide privacy, not anonymity, this is a crucial difference.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are concerned about privacy and also assuming you are talking about client web traffic you may also want to consider other ways in which your location or identity may be leaking out.

Some of which include:

IPv6 traffic not forwarded through the VPN which may provide geolocation
Cookies from primary website
Third-party Cookies
Cookie-like identifiers stored in things like Flash
HTML5 Geolocation within the http/https traffic
correlation of your web use pattern
correlation of your use of language
correlation of unique browser identity objects especially as they may relate to browser plug-ins
Anything unique to you that may help correlate your actions back to you
etc....

Other protocols will have additional issues.

Think of a VPN as a single security control which provides you with a very specific type of protection from one single vector of attack. It doesn't protect you from all of the other vectors of attack.

That said, ultimately the answer to your question is yes there are many other things to consider in respect to privacy when using a VPN.